# Interfacing 20x4 character LCD with TI TM4C1294 generates some random characters

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, lcd

I have a 20x4 character LCD connected to my TI TM4C1294 kit as follows:

1. Data bus to port A.
2. RS, RW and E pins to port L 0-2

I wrote this code in order to drive it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/tm4c1294ncpdt.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"

void LCD_SendChar(short c)
{
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_DATA_R = c;
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R |= 0x01;
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R |= 0x04;
    // asm ("   NOP");
    SysCtlDelay(18);
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R &= ~(0x04);
    SysCtlDelay(10000);
}

void LCD_SendCmd(short command)
{
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_DATA_R = command;
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R |= 0x00;
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R |= 0x04;
    // asm ("   NOP");
    SysCtlDelay(18);
    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R &= ~(0x04);
    SysCtlDelay(10000);
}

void LCD_SendString(char* value)
{
    while(*value != 0)
    {
        LCD_SendChar(*value++);
    }
}

void LCD_Init()
{
    LCD_SendCmd(0x01);
    LCD_SendCmd(0x38);
    LCD_SendCmd(0x0E);
    LCD_SendCmd(0x06);
    LCD_SendCmd(0x02);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Enable clock gating control for GPIO A and L
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R10;
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R0;

    // Wait until GPIO blocks are ready.
    while((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R & SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R10) == 0);
    while((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R & SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R0 ) == 0){};

    // Configure as Output, digital, no alternate or analog functions.
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_DIR_R = 0xFF;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_DEN_R = 0xFF;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_AFSEL_R = 0x0;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_AMSEL_R = 0x0;
    GPIO_PORTA_AHB_PCTL_R  = 0x0;

    GPIO_PORTL_DIR_R = 0x7;
    GPIO_PORTL_DEN_R = 0x7;
    GPIO_PORTL_AFSEL_R = 0x0;
    GPIO_PORTL_AMSEL_R = 0x0;
    GPIO_PORTL_PCTL_R  = 0x0;

    GPIO_PORTL_DATA_R = 0x00;
    SysCtlDelay(2200000);

    LCD_Init();

    LCD_SendCmd(0x94);
    LCD_SendString("Hello World!");
    LCD_SendCmd(0xD4);
    LCD_SendString("Hello World!");

    while (1);

}
```

The board is running at a 120MHz speed.

The problem is with line addressing. I found out that the line addressing for a 20x4 LCD are `0x80`, `0xC0`, `0x94`, `0xD4` for lines 1 to 3 respectively. When sending a "Hello World" on two lines as shown the two strings are displayed on the same line with a random character between. If I try one "Hello World" for one line while changing line address each time it works fine. What could be the reason for not addressing the lines correctly? and what's the deal with such random characters?

I suspect with:

1. Values provided for each delay function are not accurate.
2. I have read that I have to check if the LCD is busy or not but I did not understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show also the code that works instead of describing it.

Comment: I don't have a code that works.

Comment: So what is this supposed to mean: _If I try one "Hello World" for one line while changing line address each time it works fine_

Comment: I do not see where you change the strobe signal. Sometimes such a problems are involved by 3.3 logic and 5V LCD. Check it with your datasheet. PS - forget about reading from the 20x4 LCD as it is pointless. Check your delays with the oscilloscope.